# question about compactness proof in complete metric space!

Tags: analysis

I cannot solve this:

> Let $X$ be a complete metric space. Suppose that for any 
>   $r> 0$ there are finite points $x_1, x_2, \dots ,x_n$ such that
>   $N_r(x_1),\dots, N_r(x_n)$ cover $X$. Show that $X$ is compact.

Comment: It is not trivial, and it is called *total boundedness*. To begin, read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space#Relationships_with_compactness_and_completeness

Comment: I reformatted using LaTeX syntax. The property you mention is called “total boundedness” (or also “precompactness”) and *together* with completeness it indeed implies compactness.

Comment: Thanks you, egreg for converting that into nice version. I read wikipedia link in the comment. So, How can I construct Cauchy sequence using the finite points above?

Comment: Hmmmm it looks quite difficult..... I am now in rudin's chapter 3, and this was one of 6 problems in 75 minutes exam in the lecture of my professor's last semester. I rather take exam freely because everybody cannot solve the probl like this uuu

Comment: By "finite points", do you mean finitely _many_ points?  If not, then what is a "finite point"?

Comment: "fintely many points" I think.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_k$ be a sequence in $X$.  Show that $a_k$ has a cauchy subsequence, which by completeness, converges.  Then since $a_k$ is arbitrary, $X$ is sequentially compact, so compact.

Take $r_j$ decreasing to $0$.  Then for $r_1$ cover $X$ by finitely many balls of radius $r_1$.  There are therefore infinitely many $a_k$ in one such ball.  Reduce the sequence $a_k$ to the subsequence containing only those terms in the chosen ball, and choose one such term to be $b_1$.

Continue in this way with $r_2$, $r_3$, etc to get a cauchy subsequence $b_i$ of $a_k$, where at the $n$-th step we take a cover by finitely many balls of radius $r_n$, note that one such ball has infinitely many terms of the subsequence of $a_k$ that we got from the previous step, further reduce this subsequence of $a_k$ to just the terms in this chosen ball, and then choose $b_n$ to be one such term with index chosen higher than previous terms of $b_i$.  This gives a cauchy subsequence of $a_k$.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Because I don't know about sequential compactness, I cannot fully understand the argument above. I would rather study about sequential compactness more, and then reading this again may help me solve this problem completely. Thanks!

Comment: @user143299 no problem.  Sequential compactness just means that every sequence has a convergent subsequence and is equivalent to compactess in metric spaces.  You should be able to find a proof in most analysis or topology books.